# Global css in nativescript-vue project

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nativescript

I'm new to nativescript-vue, I have scaffolded my app with vue-cli and nativescript-vue template, my folder structure is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPtRH.jpg

Notice both global.scss and app.scss, none of the styles in these files are being applied in my .vue single file components, did I miss something?

Comment: Are you declaring the language on the single file component style ? eg `<style lang="scss">`

Comment: Not really, why should I do that in components for a file that is supossed to be global, I will try anyway.

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to your vue.config.js (or create one if you don't have it)

```
module.exports = {

   css: {
      loaderOptions: {
          scss: {
              prependData: `@import "~@/app.scss";`
          },
      }
   } 
}
```

Then declare the language on the component style. As from [vue-cli docs:](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors)

> Then you can import the corresponding file types, or use them in *.vue files with:
>
> ```
> <style lang="scss">
> $color: red;
> </style>
> ```

Comment: still nothing sadly